# How to upload file using multipart/form-data through python for telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am making a simple telegram bot in python through google colab and want to upload voice note through sendVoice method and want Telegram clients to display the file as a playable voice message. for that i have found from Telegram bot API manual that i must use multipart/form-data to upload audio to bot.
What is this multipart/form-data and how can i upload and use it through sendVoice method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send a file in the following manner via telebot and you don't need to worry about form-data.

```
    f = open('file_path', 'rb')
    bot.send_audio(chat_id, f)
```